# Amana washing machine making a humming noise and vibrating

Tags: washing-machine

My Amana washing machine is not working correctly. The machine was starting like normal but then it would just start humming and do nothing. I tried unplugging it and plugging it back in. It spins half a rotation and then does nothing.

@edbeal model number : ntw4516FW1

Comment: The model number of the washing machine would be a big help.

Comment: the model number is ntw4516FW1

Comment: not getting any help here..

Comment: Not much to go on, looking at a trouble shooting guide using your model# the guide says a lid lock error can cause the problem but then states this model may not have a lock because the basket spins slower (you did not mention any error codes) with mechanical controls there won't be any error codes. The next item on the list was if the machine was not filling enough to trip the water level pressure switch it won't start. There are guides on line that go through every part of the troubleshooting process. Through motor replacement, it could even be a broken motor coupler if direct drive.